# Branching and merging on a Talend project

Tags: svn, merge, talend

We use Talend Enterprise and we have it connected to our SVN server.
That gives us the ability to create new branches to start new devs / bugfixes.

I still have not found a way to smartly merge the devs from a branch to another branch / trunk.

The only tools I know about to help me merge are:

1. the ability to copy one job at a time from one branch to another
2. there is a job compare function

What I find most frustrating is that:

1. I have to remember the jobs we have been changing, as there is no way to check the differences from two branches (apart checking jobs one by one by hand);
2. I have to manually copy every single job from one branch to the destination;
3. the job compare is quite slow, so it is not applicable every now an then;

I think that not having a merge tool and resorting to copying the jobs one by one is frustrating and error prone

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that pretty much covers everything.

What you have to remember is that while it's technically using SVN in the background the Talend repository is quite a bit different to how it works compared to a normal SVN repository. To some extent you could get away with using Tortoise SVN (other SVN clients are available) to do your merging etc but be forewarned that from discussions with Talend this may invalidate your support contract if you mess it up and break your project(s).

For me personally I tend to take the trunk as the main development workspace and do all development in there. Normally my team will be working on separate projects so there's no overlap but when we work in the same space we will still restrict ourselves to working on set jobs in the project. This means we don't tend to take any separate branches from the main development trunk.

Then for releasing we take a tag of the trunk which is a read only branch. This gives us a stable basis for testing and then for releasing to production.

If any bugs are found in a release and development in the trunk has moved too far to correct it and deploy that as a new tag then we can take a branch of the tag and make any necessary changes there, releasing a fixed tag from this fixed branch. We'd then back port the necessary fix to the trunk.

This represents the general plan for how this needs to happen but in reality we try and keep changes to things small and ship in an agile manner so the trunk shouldn't (ideally) be that far from the testing and production environments. The only time we're really worried about this whole merging process is when we make a fundamental change to the architecture of a project and are massively refactoring huge chunks of it. This should obviously be once in a blue moon type changes though.

Comment: I agree that SVN usage is to be regarded as internal to Talend, I used Tortoise SVN only to debug some problems in committing.

Probably I just had to redesign half of our Data WareHouse to respond to a change in how Users are implemented in our product, so BIG changes and on many jobs all together. 

Would love to be able to better control what is changed between one release and the current development to be able to merge, even by hand, knowing for sure what has to be merged, not just trying to remember it.

Comment: Unfortunately, and as I said, there's nothing better at merging in Talend. I tend to try and avoid any needs to merge anything back into the trunk because SVN isn't great for that anyway (in my experience) and Talend's take on SVN is awful at it.